# Stop tensorflow training process programmatically

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I'm writing some platform for run trainigs on the server and I need some option to halt the training process via API. It's mean when I receive somr request to REST controller, the main threads need to stop the training that can take some days time long.
I see that Tensorflow have Coordinator class and EarlyStopping callback, but I don't see nothing that can stop thetraining by demand.
Something like: `model.stop()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can but it is a bit different.

You can't tell model to stop but the model can ask you if it should stop. That is done using a callback.
Here is a simple thing that you could do:

1. Implement your callback
   [documentation here](https://keras.io/guides/writing_your_own_callbacks/). Your callback could check for, let's say, a file in a folder. Just an example "../.../stop_training.txt"
2. Add your callback to your model with the event you want to use.
3. Create an API called "https://..../stop-training" which just creates that stop_training.txt file.

Comment: Yes, I see, and main attribute here is self.model.stop_training of Keras API